# Google Chrome: Is there a way to change the default settings on the printer page?

Tags: google-chrome

It's a very simple thing, yet so difficult in Google Chrome. I want to set the "pages per sheet" to 2 instead of 1 under more settings , everytime I hit ctrl + p. It always goes back to 1. Is there a way of doing this or to save the settings that I just changed to? Many thanks.

Comment: Not to be too pessimistic, but I would wonder if a feature like this would even exist. Chrome broadly seems to like having rather locked down print options.

Comment: @Anaksunaman thanks. That sounds really pessimistic. I guess I'm gonna have to change it every time I hit the print button. This doesn't make any sense that we can't change the default settings in any way.